# Superdense coding projects

Tags: resource-request, superdense-coding

I have recently been studying quantum computing specially the cryptographic aspects of it. The books I followed is Nielsen and Chuang, and a book named Quantum Computing Explained by David McMohan. The chapter that got me really interested in quantum computing was the superdense coding one. I was just curious to know if there are some projects or problems related to these topics which one can start doing. Can somebody give useful links for these topics?